# Multithreading on AVR

Tags: avr, interrupts, thread

If I have an AVR micro controller and have an ISR coming up about every 100 micro seconds or so, can I change the stack pointer in the ISR and then fake multi threading?

Psuedo code:

```
uint8_t currentThread = 0;
void* process0StackPointer = 0;
uint8_t process0SREG = 0;
void* process1StackPointer = 0;
uint8_t process1SREG = 0;
ISR(TIMER0_OCA_vect)
{
  currentThread = !currentThread;
  if (currentThread == 0)
  {
    process0StackPointer = StackPointer;  //Back up the stack pointer of the
    //"0" thread and the status register
    process0SREG = SREG;
    StackPointer = process1StackPointer 
  }
  else
  {
    process1StackPointer = StackPointer;  //Back up the stack pointer of the
    //"1" thread and the status register
    process1SREG = SREG;
    StackPointer = process0StackPointer 
  }

}
```

Is this a plausible thing to do, or is there something that I am not seeing here?

Comment: First: "... have an ISR coming up about every 100 nano seconds" would require the ISR to be serviced in *less* than 100 nano seconds. One AVR instruction, at its maximum clock of 20MHz, is 50ns or longer. So no, it couldn't service an ISR in any way whatsoever.

Comment: Did you happen to mean 100 micro seconds?

Comment: that is how multithreading works, at some point in an interrupt handler, the handler (kernel, operating system, rtos, whatever term you want) saves state of the prior task and restores state for the next task from when it was interrupted.  lather rinse repeat.

Comment: @sa_leinad I did mean 100 micro seconds.....oops

Comment: Congrats - you are about to invent an operating system. I suggest reading up on operating system theory. FreeRTOS is open and will tell you how it works. uCOS is a high-quality one and their textbook will teach you everything you wanted to know about an embedded operating system, but their licensing is expensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create an adequate multi-threading system, you need to do a 'context switch' see [Wikipedia 'context switch'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) for an explanation.

The code needs to make the 'context switch' be 'invisible' to each thread. Otherwise a thread will not be possible to restart reliably, destroying the value of doing it.

To make an invisible context switch to any running thread **all** of its state needs to be saved. It isn't sufficient to just save the SREG (status register), and flip to another stack. It needs to save *all* registers that could possibly be in use. Clearly the obvious set is the entire AVR register file, 32 registers. They would need to be saved, and the register file for the thread about to be resumed loaded in such a way that everything will be restored to the *same state* at the point that thread was previously interrupted.

Summary: yes an AVR multi-threaded system could be built using a timer, however, your code needs to save and restore a lot more state.

As I said in my comment, an AVR running at its highest speed of 20MHz, needs one or more cycles to complete one instruction. It would take about 32 instructions, and hence 64 cycles to store all of the 32 registers into memory, and about 64 cycles more to load the registers for a different thread, plus a little bit more for IRS entry and exit.

So, you should estimate about 140 cycles to create the most basic multi-threading context switch. That is 7µs at 20MHz clock. I'd suggest you keep the context switch well under 10% of the available CPU cycles so that it can actually get some useful work done. So have the interrupt less frequent than 70µs.

A possible place to help you understand the scope of the issues is to look at an existing simple OS. Then you will understand all of the other pieces which are likely to be needed more quickly. For example something like [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/).

This ['Arduino OS' forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=138643.0) page may help too.

A lot of the context switch code will need to be in assembler because you can't reliably get at the registers from C. However, because the AVR's instruction set is relatively simple, that shouldn't be too hard.

Each thread is usually represented by several different chunks of memory (RAM):
1. The register values
2. The stack

Atmel's AVR don't have a lot of RAM, so one awkward part is allocating enough stack for the thread, without using so much memory that there isn't room for enough threads.

The last little wrinkle that I remember is an exit from ISR (RETI) isn't *exactly* the same as a return from subroutine (RET), so you'll need to think that through too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, with qualifications.

Simply changing the stack pointer won't be sufficient to switch threads; you will also need to store the values of all 32 registers at the time your ISR is called from a given thread, and restore the original values when switching back to that thread. Between this and the need to store and modify the stack pointer, this will all mean that the ISR must be written in assembly.

You'll also need to allocate a separate stack for each thread. The AVR default stack starts at the top of memory and extends downward from there; you will need to allocate a separate stack somewhere else in memory for any secondary threads.

Between all of this, you will find that writing (and, worse, debugging!) this functionality will be quite difficult. I'd strongly advise you to find another way to structure your program if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

**When the question was originally posted the interrupt rate was specified as 100nsec. So I responded:**

At 100 nsec interrupt rate that corresponds to a frequency of 10 MHz. If you had an AVR with a 100 MHz clock rate (and that is way higher than most parts in Atmel's AVR family) that would result in there being only 10 clocks available to respond to and handle each interrupt. Keeping in mind that most of the AVRs are slower than 100 MHz then even less clocks are available to process each interrupt.

I can suggest that five or ten clocks cycles will never be enough to process any kind of real world type interrupt service routine. For this type of MCU I strongly suggest that you back the period of your periodic interrupt input down to something more on the order of 1 to 10 milliseconds.

**Now that the OP has changed to 100usec rate here is my response:**

At a 100 usec interrupt rate that corresponds to a frequency of 10 KHz. If your AVR is one with a typical operating frequency of 20 MHz this will correspond to:

20 MHz / 10 KHz = 2000 clock cycles per interrupt. At this rate it is possible to support interrupt service routines that have a carefully managed amount of code within the interrupt context.

At to whether it is plausible to create an RTOS with full context switch using an interrupt rate like this is something that you will have to calculate. For example if you write code to do the context switch at each interrupt time and find that the code takes 200 clock cycles to complete then it is easy to see that 10% of the MCU's compute bandwidth is consumed just with performing overhead work before a given task can run.

*I have personally coded dozens of embedded MCU applications that have never even come close to needing/requiring an RTOS.* Some of these embedded applications were projects that had the appearance of 30, 40 or even 50 things all happening at the same time. Here are some of the reasons I stay away from RTOS applications:

1. Context switching overhead is expensive in terms of overall overhead if you try to code for sub millisecond task latency.
2. In limited resource MCUs like AVRs there is only so much RAM available. Using up a good chunk of it to store task contexts and task control blocks may be a penalty that is too high for many applications.
3. RTOS Task environment requires also that there be memory pool management between tasks. If it gets managed as a heap with dynamic allocation there is additional processing overhead to perform the heap management. On the other hand if you select the simpler approach and decide on a fixed allocation of memory per task then you place arbitrary limits on maximum memory available to a given task and some tasks with small memory footprint will be sitting on unused memory.
4. RTOS usage almost always pushes a given application up at least one or two notches of processor family capabilities and resources which increases BOM cost.
5. For "roll your own" RTOS usage there is always going to be an extra burden placed on your project to maintain the code, fix bugs and fine tune performance issues that detract from building the actual product that should get 100% attention.
6. If you use a third party RTOS there is extra work added to the product development to learn how to use it, there may be extra costs involved if it is a commercial product and you may still be faced with bugs and performance issues.

I often think that the only folks that really make money or reap tangible benefits from an RTOS are those that make the RTOS products and convince other engineers that they are needed in order to get real time work out of an MCU.

Comment: This answer is a bit out of date now that OP edited the question, he's now running at 100 µs instead of 100 ns.

Comment: @pipe - Oh well it is a dynamic site.

Comment: Your answer seems to assume that this is a "real" project......on the contrary this is just so that I can have "fun" building a multithreaded program on AVR

Comment: @DarthRubik - Not so. I would not invest my time even for a hobby project in such endeavor on an AVR. If I make a time investment in something it is in an effort that teaches and gives experience in something practical and useful for further money making opportunities. Before setting out on things to learn and spend time on I also research and learn from experts on the subject so as to maximize the value of my time and not learn bad habits and techniques.

Answer (score 1):

There are other approaches to handle concurrency and hard real-time requirements, see e.g. [Atom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/atom). I've experimented with this package targeting an ATMega328p and got it to work. It's not that well documented but the ideas are interesting.